# Prove that the space of square-integrable functions which is also denoted by $L^2(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $h,g$ be square-integrable functions on $\Omega\subset \Bbb R$.  Prove that under the product $$\langle g,h\rangle:=\int_{\Omega}g(x)h(x)dx$$ the space of square-integrable functions which is also denoted by $L^2(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert space.

I am asking for a well organized elementary way of clearly answering this question.  Here is my way of seeing it but I am not so confortable:

(a) Verify/Show that $\langle g,h\rangle:=\int_{\Omega}g(x)h(x)dx$ is an inner-product on $\Omega$.  That is, it satisfies the following:

(i) $\langle g,g\rangle\geq 0$ and $\langle g,g\rangle= 0$ iff $g=0$;

(ii) $\langle ag+bf,h\rangle=a\langle g,h\rangle+b\langle f,h\rangle$;

(iii) $\langle g,ah\rangle=a\overline{\langle h,g\rangle}$;

(b) Show that $L^2(\Omega)$ is complete.  However, I also have issues in showing this.  Most functional analysis books have proved $L^2(\Bbb R^d)$.

**Question** Is there a well written answer for my question in a book or hand out?

Comment: Unfortunately, if there was a nicer proof, the books would use that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition for the inner product should be
$$\langle g, h \rangle = \int_{\Omega}g(x)\overline{h(x)}\,dx.$$
Also note that $g, h \in L^2(\Omega) \implies g\overline{h} \in L^1(\Omega)$ by Holder's inequality, so the inner product is well defined. Condition (a)(iii) should be $\langle g, h \rangle = \overline{\langle h, g \rangle}$.

Let $g \in L^2(\Omega)$. We have
$$\langle g, g \rangle = \int_{\Omega}g(x)\overline{g(x)}\,dx = \int_{\Omega}|g(x)|^2\,dx.$$
It is a classic exercise that if $f \geq 0$ is measurable, then $\int_{\Omega}f(x)\,dx = 0$ if and only if $f = 0$ almost everywhere (this holds for any measure space $\Omega$). Thus $\langle g, g \rangle = 0$ if and only if $g = 0$ since by definition, $f_1 = f_2$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ if $f_1 = f_2$ almost everywhere. Property (a)(ii) follows from the linearity of the integral on $L^1(\Omega)$. Property (a)(iii) follows from the identity $\overline{\int_{\Omega}f(x)\,dx} = \int_{\Omega}\overline{f(x)}\,dx$,which itself follows from the linearity of the integral on $L^1(\Omega)$ (write $f = g + ih$).

(b) is not difficult to prove if you have the monotone convergence and dominated convergence theorems. A proof is given in "Real Analysis" by Folland on page 183 (theorem 6.6). The idea is to use the fact that a normed vector space $V$ is complete if and only if every absolutley convergent series is convergent, i.e. $v_1, v_2, \dots \in V$, $\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}\lVert v_j \rVert < \infty \implies \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}v_j = v$ for some $v \in V$.